# Vega-Lite gradient legend with box plots

Tags: bar-chart, legend, boxplot, vega-lite, color-gradient

I am trying to set a gradient legend as described [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/legend.html#legend-types) on a vega-lite box plot. Even by setting the color encoding as "quantitative", the legend remains with symbols.

You can compare the behavior of [bar chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9uAQwAecSnhAAbOQCNMagIJQEazJIBsXdVp0AxXgGU4AL2PIAjCe7FCRm0XtOUbrLqmAiYUHR40kGMIghikgCs5tj0TJIc3AAklGAxALZyKCBihAAOlMgA9JVoIXIAdAhwTKSa9XAQlTn5cjV1ALRqzZg1CfUAVpTQINx0mDkATnClxNPIILoABLULxGByapuaEAqbpWoQhJuUjBApBpt5mHRwclCbb3SbF9iYCx-hTakUqlP6bACOpDkuzgRkomwgME2TEwmxelEIS00pFW70RRwgdAAno85JR4fjQQZSCRKPUZiA6HJCIVUCBSAs1EUmSzKvsFnTJtMggUFgBrVSEImgoqaaEMiBLMLida3JYOXgHBmURzOFwJIJhSAvAyqBSqeA6CLrACysPmAH1QQsHQBxA4XKAMqUy9aQt6eZlwWogIKQC4LC1YNTWkAAYSJQ3CfxUHmlzhA-qIzSDIaCRKjVqKCaTcwF3vTRSzgeIIe4OQOzlATgWEBQMAOlEwUSiQA) vs. [box plot](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9uAQwAecSnhAAbOQCNMagIJQEazJIBsXdVp0AxXgGU4AL2PIAjCe7FCRm0XtOUbrLqmAiYUHR40kGMIghikgCs5tj0TJIc3AAklGAxALZyKCBihAAOlMgA9JVoIXIAdAhwTKSa9XAQlTn5cjV1ALRqzZg1CfUAVpTQINx0mDkATnClxNPIILoABLULxGByapuaEAqbpWoQhJuUjBApBpt5mHRwclCbb3SbF9iYCx-hTakUqlP6bACOpDkuzgRkomwgME2TEwmxelEIS00pFW70RRwgdAAno85JR4fjQQZSCRKPUZiA6HJCIVUCBSAs1EUmSzKvsFnTJtMggUFgBrVSEImgorHBTnS4MiBLMLida3JYOXgHBmURzOFwJIJhSAvAyqBSqeA6CLrACysPmAH1QQsnQBxA4XKAMqUy9aQt6eZlwWogIKQC4LK1YNS2kAAYSJQ3CfxUHmlzhAgaIzRDYe4mhIKBgB0omCCRJjNqKSZTcwFvszRRzweIBZAOQOzlATgWEBLZYrUWkQA) with quantitative color encoding. The legend on the bar chart is a gradient one, while on the box plot it is with symbols.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is causing this inconsistent behaviour for bar chart and box plot. This works normally but as an alternative for getting the gradient legend you can use the `fill` config instead of `color` as it seems to bring the expected legend for `quantitative` type.

Refer the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9uAQwAecSnhAAbOQCNMagIJQEazJIBsXdVp0AxXgGU4AL2PIAjCe7FCRm0XtOUbrLqmAiYUHR40kGMIghikgCs5tj0TJIc3AAklGAxALZyKCBihAAOlMgA9JVoIXIAdAhwTKSa9XAQlTn5cjV1ALRqzZg1CfUAVpTQINx0mDkATnClxNPIILoABLULxGByapuaEAqbpWoQhJuUjBApBpt5mHRwclCbb3SbF9iYCx-hTakUqlP6bACOpDkuzgRkomwgME2TEwmxelEIS00pFW70RRwgdAAno85JR4fjQQZSCRKPUZiA6HJCIVUCBSAs1EUmSzKvsFnTJtMggUFgBrVSEImgorHBTnS4MiBLMLida3JYOXgHBmURzOFwJbhPF5vVQYhYQMXOEDYRjDXWYq2YWgMZjINj1BJRbhhSAvAyqBSqeA6CLrACysPmAH1QQsYwBxA4XKAMqUy9aQt6eZlwWogILwNRctmhtThkAAYSJQ3CfxUHmlNuzRGaeYL3E0JBQMAOlEwQSJIawFaKNbrcwF6ebRVbueIBai0iAA) of below snippet:

```
{
  "config": {
    "view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300},
    "axis": {"labelAngle": 360, "labelFontSize": 16, "titleFontSize": 16},
    "legend": {}
  },
  "height": 350,
  "width": 300,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A vertical box plot showing median and lower and upper quartiles of the distribution of body mass of penguins.",
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "boxplot",
    "orient": "horizontal",
    "size": 15,
    "median": {"stroke": "white", "strokeWidth": 0.5}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fill": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "quantitative", "bin": false},
    "y": {"field": "Cylinders", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed, setting "fill" encoding instead of "color" encoding solves the problem. However, it creates a new one: the median line on the box disappears... Do you have a fix for that too?

Comment: Yes, you can provide `median` in `mark` config with its stroke color and width. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I accepted this answer.